# "Clickable" Links and Text Inputs in canvas-powered Page Flip demo

Tags: jquery, css, input, hyperlink, html5-canvas

I'm using the Page Flip demo (tutorial **[here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/20things_pageflip/)** and demo **[here](http://www.html5rocks.com/static/demos/20things_pageflip/example/index.html)**) from Google's HTML5-based web app, *[20 Things I Learned about Browsers and the Web](http://www.20thingsilearned.com/)* as a base for a website I am creating.

In short, the book works by putting the content directly in the DOM (search-engine friendly) and manipulating it using javascript. The page flip animation is drawn onto an overlaid canvas element.

I ran into problems when I started adding links and a contact form to my book. For some reason the links and input elements aren't "clickable".

I've created a jsFiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/indieweb/HTC9G/)** to demonstrate.

**I thought it might be a z-index issue:** The overlaid canvas z-index is set to 100. Page z-indices start at 0 and work their way up to the front of the book. What if I brought the links/inputs to the front with a higher z-index?

But changing the z-index of the offending elements didn't solve the problem. And anyway, the pages themselves are layered using z-indices so even if bringing the links/inputs to the top layer did work, it wouldn't be a workable solution because then the links wouldn't be layered correctly with their respective pages.

**How do I solve this issue:** *make links and input elements "clickable" under/through a canvas?*

---

**HTML:**

```
    <body>
        <div id="book">

            <canvas id="pageflip-canvas"></canvas>

            <div id="pages">

                <section>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Test Page</h2>
                        <p>This demo is fantastic! ...apart from the fact that link and input elements aren't supported. The canvas element and JS on which the entire magic relies, renders both "unclickable" - a major drawback. See below:</p>
                        <a href="#">Click me!</a>
                        <input type="text"></input>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <div>
                        <h2>History</h2>
                        <p>Canvas was initially introduced by Apple for use inside their own Mac OS X WebKit component, powering applications like Dashboard widgets and the Safari browser. Later, it was adopted by Gecko browsers and Opera and standardized by the WHATWG on new proposed specifications for next generation web technologies.</p>
                    </div>
                </section>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

---

**CSS:**

```
    body, h2, p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    body {
        background-color: #444;
        color: #333;
        font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    #book {
        background: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3799114/page-flip-demo/book.png") no-repeat;
        position: absolute;
        width: 830px;
        height: 260px;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        margin-left: -400px;
        margin-top: -125px;
    }

    #pages section {
        background: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3799114/page-flip-demo/paper.png") no-repeat;
        display: block;
        width: 400px;
        height: 250px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 415px;
        top: 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
        #pages section>div {
            display: block;
            width: 400px;
            height: 250px;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        #pages section p,
        #pages section h2 {
            padding: 3px 35px;
            line-height: 1.4em;
            text-align: justify;
        }
        #pages section h2{
            margin: 15px 0 10px;
        }

    #pageflip-canvas {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
    }
```

---

**jQuery:**

```
(function() {

// Dimensions of the whole book
var BOOK_WIDTH = 830;
var BOOK_HEIGHT = 260;

// Dimensions of one page in the book
var PAGE_WIDTH = 400;
var PAGE_HEIGHT = 250;

// Vertical spacing between the top edge of the book and the papers
var PAGE_Y = ( BOOK_HEIGHT - PAGE_HEIGHT ) / 2;

// The canvas size equals to the book dimensions + this padding
var CANVAS_PADDING = 60;

var page = 0;

var canvas = document.getElementById( "pageflip-canvas" );
var context = canvas.getContext( "2d" );

var mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };

var flips = [];

var book = document.getElementById( "book" );

// List of all the page elements in the DOM
var pages = book.getElementsByTagName( "section" );

// Organize the depth of our pages and create the flip definitions
for( var i = 0, len = pages.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    pages[i].style.zIndex = len - i;

    flips.push( {
        // Current progress of the flip (left -1 to right +1)
        progress: 1,
        // The target value towards which progress is always moving
        target: 1,
        // The page DOM element related to this flip
        page: pages[i], 
        // True while the page is being dragged
        dragging: false
    } );
}

// Resize the canvas to match the book size
canvas.width = BOOK_WIDTH + ( CANVAS_PADDING * 2 );
canvas.height = BOOK_HEIGHT + ( CANVAS_PADDING * 2 );

// Offset the canvas so that it's padding is evenly spread around the book
canvas.style.top = -CANVAS_PADDING + "px";
canvas.style.left = -CANVAS_PADDING + "px";

// Render the page flip 60 times a second
setInterval( render, 1000 / 60 );

document.addEventListener( "mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false );
document.addEventListener( "mousedown", mouseDownHandler, false );
document.addEventListener( "mouseup", mouseUpHandler, false );

function mouseMoveHandler( event ) {
    // Offset mouse position so that the top of the book spine is 0,0
    mouse.x = event.clientX - book.offsetLeft - ( BOOK_WIDTH / 2 );
    mouse.y = event.clientY - book.offsetTop;
}

function mouseDownHandler( event ) {
    // Make sure the mouse pointer is inside of the book
    if (Math.abs(mouse.x) < PAGE_WIDTH) {
        if (mouse.x < 0 && page - 1 >= 0) {
            // We are on the left side, drag the previous page
            flips[page - 1].dragging = true;
        }
        else if (mouse.x > 0 && page + 1 < flips.length) {
            // We are on the right side, drag the current page
            flips[page].dragging = true;
        }
    }

    // Prevents the text selection
    event.preventDefault();
}

function mouseUpHandler( event ) {
    for( var i = 0; i < flips.length; i++ ) {
        // If this flip was being dragged, animate to its destination
        if( flips[i].dragging ) {
            // Figure out which page we should navigate to
            if( mouse.x < 0 ) {
                flips[i].target = -1;
                page = Math.min( page + 1, flips.length );
            }
            else {
                flips[i].target = 1;
                page = Math.max( page - 1, 0 );
            }
        }

        flips[i].dragging = false;
    }
}

function render() {

    // Reset all pixels in the canvas
    context.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

    for( var i = 0, len = flips.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        var flip = flips[i];

        if( flip.dragging ) {
            flip.target = Math.max( Math.min( mouse.x / PAGE_WIDTH, 1 ), -1 );
        }

        // Ease progress towards the target value 
        flip.progress += ( flip.target - flip.progress ) * 0.2;

        // If the flip is being dragged or is somewhere in the middle of the book, render it
        if( flip.dragging || Math.abs( flip.progress ) < 0.997 ) {
            drawFlip( flip );
        }

    }

}

function drawFlip( flip ) {
    // Strength of the fold is strongest in the middle of the book
    var strength = 1 - Math.abs( flip.progress );

    // Width of the folded paper
    var foldWidth = ( PAGE_WIDTH * 0.5 ) * ( 1 - flip.progress );

    // X position of the folded paper
    var foldX = PAGE_WIDTH * flip.progress + foldWidth;

    // How far the page should outdent vertically due to perspective
    var verticalOutdent = 20 * strength;

    // The maximum width of the left and right side shadows
    var paperShadowWidth = ( PAGE_WIDTH * 0.5 ) * Math.max( Math.min( 1 - flip.progress, 0.5 ), 0 );
    var rightShadowWidth = ( PAGE_WIDTH * 0.5 ) * Math.max( Math.min( strength, 0.5 ), 0 );
    var leftShadowWidth = ( PAGE_WIDTH * 0.5 ) * Math.max( Math.min( strength, 0.5 ), 0 );


    // Change page element width to match the x position of the fold
    flip.page.style.width = Math.max(foldX, 0) + "px";

    context.save();
    context.translate( CANVAS_PADDING + ( BOOK_WIDTH / 2 ), PAGE_Y + CANVAS_PADDING );


    // Draw a sharp shadow on the left side of the page
    context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,'+(0.05 * strength)+')';
    context.lineWidth = 30 * strength;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(foldX - foldWidth, -verticalOutdent * 0.5);
    context.lineTo(foldX - foldWidth, PAGE_HEIGHT + (verticalOutdent * 0.5));
    context.stroke();


    // Right side drop shadow
    var rightShadowGradient = context.createLinearGradient(foldX, 0, foldX + rightShadowWidth, 0);
    rightShadowGradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,'+(strength*0.2)+')');
    rightShadowGradient.addColorStop(0.8, 'rgba(0,0,0,0.0)');

    context.fillStyle = rightShadowGradient;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(foldX, 0);
    context.lineTo(foldX + rightShadowWidth, 0);
    context.lineTo(foldX + rightShadowWidth, PAGE_HEIGHT);
    context.lineTo(foldX, PAGE_HEIGHT);
    context.fill();


    // Left side drop shadow
    var leftShadowGradient = context.createLinearGradient(foldX - foldWidth - leftShadowWidth, 0, foldX - foldWidth, 0);
    leftShadowGradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,0.0)');
    leftShadowGradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0,'+(strength*0.15)+')');

    context.fillStyle = leftShadowGradient;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(foldX - foldWidth - leftShadowWidth, 0);
    context.lineTo(foldX - foldWidth, 0);
    context.lineTo(foldX - foldWidth, PAGE_HEIGHT);
    context.lineTo(foldX - foldWidth - leftShadowWidth, PAGE_HEIGHT);
    context.fill();


    // Gradient applied to the folded paper (highlights & shadows)
    var foldGradient = context.createLinearGradient(foldX - paperShadowWidth, 0, foldX, 0);
    foldGradient.addColorStop(0.35, '#fafafa');
    foldGradient.addColorStop(0.73, '#eeeeee');
    foldGradient.addColorStop(0.9, '#fafafa');
    foldGradient.addColorStop(1.0, '#e2e2e2');

    context.fillStyle = foldGradient;
    context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.06)';
    context.lineWidth = 0.5;

    // Draw the folded piece of paper
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(foldX, 0);
    context.lineTo(foldX, PAGE_HEIGHT);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(foldX, PAGE_HEIGHT + (verticalOutdent * 2), foldX - foldWidth, PAGE_HEIGHT + verticalOutdent);
    context.lineTo(foldX - foldWidth, -verticalOutdent);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(foldX, -verticalOutdent * 2, foldX, 0);

    context.fill();
    context.stroke();


    context.restore();
}
```

})();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually discovered a 2-fold solution requiring changes to both the CSS and jQuery (as well as a 3rd requirement to "fix" some of the resulting changes).

***Step 1: Making the Links Click-able***

In order to make links click-able the CSS attribute *pointer-events* (with a value of *none*) must be applied to the canvas element.

**CSS:**

```
    canvas {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/indieweb/xbHyz/)** showing link now click-able.

Note that the following conditional CSS statement is required for compatibility with IE:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <style type="text/css">
        canvas {
            background: none !important;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

---

***Step 2: Making the Text Inputs Click-able***

But as you can see, this does not solve the issue for the text input element, which remains un-click-able. (Interestingly radio buttons work after implementing Step 1 - not included in demo).

The solution for this lies in the jQuery (line 82 of the original demo files): the method *event.preventDefault();*

This method is in place to prevent default text selection when the mouse is dragged over the page. The mouse drag action is used to turn the page and text-selection makes the animation less attractive.

Removing or commenting out this method re-enabled text input.

**jQuery:**

```
    // event.preventDefault(); // comment out this beast
```

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/indieweb/ZbpNR/)** showing text input element now click-able.

---

***Step 3: Disable Text-Selection using CSS***

So now the 2 issues - un-click-able links and un-click-able input elements - are resolved, but the fallout of this is that default text-selection is now re-enabled, making the page flip animation less attractive.

Solution: disable text selection by applying *-webkit-touch-callout* and *user-select* (both with value *none*) to the content div for each "page".

**CSS:**

```
    #page-content-div {
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: moz-none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
```

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/indieweb/9qnrR/)** showing completed book with click-able link and text input and no text selection on page turn.